# How to handle redirect loop error in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with a php function which redirects to many to times to header. After running for 21 times or so it give below error:

```
"This website has a redirect loop" and stops running
```

Below is my redirect code:

```
header('Location: http://myfunction.com/index.php/test/mytestfunction?days=60&start='. ($start + 100) .'&end='. ($end + 100));
```

here $start and $end are limit to fetch data from database.Project is on codeigniter

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of so much redirection?

Comment: please add more code so we know why it's redirecting in loop

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like utter madness. Page redirects are intended to divert a user to a different part of the site, for various reasons. They should never be used as a means of iteration. That's what loops are intended to do.

The other possibility is that you have the `header` command in a script that isn't wrapped in any condition, and then redirects to itself (or another script that redirects back).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But my task is very different from that view. It's a script running backend to update the database everyday for once, which have millions of data.

Comment: Why is a "backend script" using `header` and running in a browser? If you need a script to run once a day then you should be using CLI and `cron` to run it.

Comment: My client told to me to first run it on browser show him it's working then I should user cron job

Comment: Even so, `header` redirects have no place in a CLI script. They don't make sense unless the script is run in a browser. I'm sensing that you're attempting to use redirects as a form of program control, which is utterly, utterly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (see code below). What you are doing with the HTTP headers makes no sense.

```
$url = 'http://myfunction.com/index.php/test/mytestfunction';
$ch = curl_init($url . '?' . http_build_query(array(
    'days' => 60,
    'start' => $start,
    'end' => $end,
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```